# Sed command to append below the specific text

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I've a scenario where I want to add some content below specific line as shown below.

```
func (v version) string(){
    vers := [...]string{
        "4",
        "5",
       //"6",         //this should be added
        "vE",
    }
```

Above is my code block and I want to add "6", below "5" using sed operation.
I've seen multiple articles and post but couldn't get the correct answer.

What I've tried is

```
    current_number = '"5",'
    next_number = '"6",'    
    os.system("sed -i /"+current_number+"/a"+next_number+" sample.txt")
```

Edit 1 : After @steffen's answer I get below error, image attached.[image]

Answer (score 1):

It works:

```
$ sed '/"5",/a"6",' file
func (v version) string(){
    vers := [...]string{
        "4",
        "5",
"6",
        "vE",
    }
```

But I think you need to add single quotes. I think your command reads:

```
sed -i /"5",/a"6", sample.txt
```

And that's equivalent to:

```
sed -i /5,/a6, sample.txt
```

Here's how to use variables:

```
PATTERN='"5",'
NEWLINE='"6",'
sed "/$PATTERN/a$NEWLINE" file
sed '/'"$PATTERN"'/a'"$NEWLINE" file # alternatively
```

The latter uses an idiomatic format, `'` for all the literals and `"` for variables.

Comment: It still get messed up while using variable? can you tell me what would be the command in the variable format ?
Plus the command somehow gives me an error when passed to os.system(xyz) attached image above in the question

Answer (score 0):

Given these variables:

```
$ current_number='"5"'
$ next_number='"6"'
```

If you really want to use sed you could do the following to retain the indentation for the new line:

```
$ sed -n 'p; s/'"$current_number"'/'"$next_number"'/p' file
func (v version) string(){
    vers := [...]string{
        "4",
        "5",
        "6",
        "vE",
    }
```

but personally I'd use awk for ease of future updates, maintenance, etc:

```
$ awk -v old="$current_number" -v new="$next_number" '{print} sub(old,new)' file
func (v version) string(){
    vers := [...]string{
        "4",
        "5",
        "6",
        "vE",
    }
```

Use `awk -i inplace ...` with GNU awk like you're using `sed -i ...` with GNU sed to update the input file.